# Variable number of arguments to Python script

Tags: python, input

The command line to run my Python script is:

```
./parse_ms.py inputfile 3 2 2 2
```

the arguments are an input, number 3 is the number of samples of my study each with 2 individuals.

In the script, I indicate the arguments as follows:

```
inputfile = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
nsam = int(sys.argv[2])
nind1 = int(sys.argv[3])
nind2 = int(sys.argv[4])
nind3 = int(sys.argv[5])
```

However, the number of samples may vary. I can have:

```
./parse_ms.py input 4 6 8 2 20
```

in this case, I have 4 samples with 6, 8, 2 and 20 individuals in each.

It seems inefficient to add another `sys.argv` everything a sample is added. Is there a way to make this more general? That is, if I write `nsam` to be equal to 5, automatically, Python excepts five numbers to follow for the individuals in each sample.

Comment: `samples = sys.argv[3:]`? or use `argparse` to parse a flag instead. Or use `shlex.split` on a group or numbers enclosed in `"`

Comment: `len(sys.arvg)` gives you the length of the input list (+1 for the executable name), so you can skip the first argument and can use a for loop with a list for arbitrary amount of arguments. There are libraries which can help you with argument parsing.

Comment: @Torxed how can we use argparse for this scenario please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation) off the rest of `sys.argv` into a list. e.g.

```
inputfile = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
num_samples = int(sys.argv[2])
samples = sys.argv[3:3+num_samples]
```

Although if that is all your arguments, you can simply not pass a number of samples and just grab everything.

```
inputfile = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
samples = sys.argv[2:]
```

Samples can be converted to the proper datatype afterward.

Also, look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for a nicer way of handling command line arguments in general.

Comment: Op wants the samples converted to ints too. Aside from that, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of ninds and even catch expections doing the following

```
try:
    ninds = [int(argv[i+3]) for i in range(int(argv[2]))]
except IndexError:
    print("Error. Expected %s samples and got %d" %(argv[2], len(argv[3:])))
```

Comment: Just updated the code. Now it works. If he needs the sample sizes as ints, should make `ninds = [int(argv[i+3]) ...]` also

Comment: I have removed my downvote. This is a bit awkward, but totally functional. Op does want `int(argv[i + 3])` though.